# How to configure rules in JSLint extension for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jslint

I tried to use JSLint.VS2012 extension to check the JavaScript code. it is useful for it found a lot syntax issues in my code. However, is it possible to configure the rules in JSLint to enable/disable certain rules? Currently, I'd like to switch off 2 rules:

1) The code format checking. Because I use Visual Studio 2012 as the editor, it has a default code formatter, the formated code is OK for me. But, seems JSLint requires a different code format style, so I prefer VS2012 auto format feature, and need switch off the JSLint rule. Here is a snapshot shows JSLint complaining the 'bad' formatted code.

[image]

2) The second I want to be disabled rule is "Unexpected 'else' after 'return':
I don't this rule is good, but guarded return could improve the readability of if-else switches, below is a snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been silent long enough I'll at least answer for VS 2008 and hope it's similar for the VS 2012 plugin.

**Question 1:** Go to your tools menu.  Select "JSLint Options".  Look for "Tolerate sloppy whitespace",[image] and check it.  Hopefully the 2012 version has a similar checkbox.

**Question 2:** The second is a little nastier.  I don't believe there's a setting to turn it off, but even the VS plugin just uses the JSLint javascript file under the hood (or at least the 2008 version does [via Noesis](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/)).  So if you want, you can open up jslint.js and edit it.

If you edit this part, the error is ignored:

```
if (peek(0).id === '}' && peek(1).id === 'else') {
    // commented out >>> this.warn('unexpected_else');
}
```

Voila.  The JSLint code really is good, clean stuff that's easy to customize.  But I am required to say that you really should take JSLint's advice, and in this case, I'd tend to agree.  But inherited code?  Comment the line out and keep moving along.

Comment: Great! this really answers my questions. I will try to follow JSLint advices.